# MAMP PHP 5.6.2 errors compiling redis.so

Tags: php, redis, mamp

I have been trying to compile a redis.so extension for MAMP using PHP 5.6.2 and I am getting a compiling error.  Mostly ‘compiler_globals’ undeclared, but a couple other Zend related ones.  I have spent hours trying to get this working.

If I try to compile using PHP 5.5.x as a source I do not have any issues.

Is there anyone who has successfully compiled a redis.so for 5.6.x?  If so is it possible to get it posted for download?  Anyone have any suggestions as to how to compile without errors?

Please don't post links to instructions on how to do the redis.so compilation as I have read gone through them and it is not working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will want the source code for PHP. Download it and rename the folder to php. Put this folder into a include folder in the MAMP php directory.

Before ./configure your extension, be sure to run ./configure in the php directory. This will create the proper header files needed for the extensions.

Also, you want to phpize from the Mamp version of php that you are running.

$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/bin/phpize